# How to make maven to obtain release parent pom instead of latest?

Tags: java, parent-pom, maven

Having declared the master POM for a project using version ranges resolves to the latest version (containing SNAPSHOT). Any way to make it resolve to release ?

Parent POM declaration inside project :

```
<parent>
  <groupId>my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-company-pom</artifactId>
  <version>(,2.0.0]</version>
</parent>
```

Parent POM metadata file

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-company-pom</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release>1.2.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>xxxxxxxxxxxx</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Why Maven resolves parent POM version to 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.2.0 ?

Comment: The master pom you mean is only for a multi module build or a general master pom file ? What not writing down the explicit version ? Why is a range needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092), it is a very old, well known and controversy bug in maven for me your best option is not to use version range in your case at all as there is no real valid workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` is the latest, in this line (6th line in parent pom metadata XML file)

```
<latest>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
```

Comment: Then how to avoid setting latest version to a SNAPSHOT ? Added to the maven repository using mvn deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude snapshot versions in a custom repository definition to solve this issue.

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>codehaus</id>
   <name>codehaus</name>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Maven just does not "see" snapshots then. Of course you have to adapt the settings (URL and so on) to your repo.